# Ruby - convert .rb to .exe

Tags: ruby

I want to convert my .rb file to .exe

I know I can use **ORCA** but it only supports till 1.9.3(?)

Does anyone know how to convert a .rb file to .exe? With ruby version 2.0.0

This error only appears if you're using ruby 2.0.0+ (according to other forums including this one)

`DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle.`

`Could not find command "test.rb".`

What was my input? `orca test.rb`

Comment: Accoriding to documentation `ocra` supports ruby 2.0.0: https://github.com/larsch/ocra

Answer (score 6):

Correct your spelling, It should be `ocra`  **not** `orca`

You are trying..

```
orca test.rb
```

instead

```
ocra test.rb
```

**[Reference](https://github.com/larsch/ocra#building-an-executable)**

**[Requirement:](https://github.com/larsch/ocra#requirements)** Working Ruby installation. **Ocra** is tested with **RubyInstaller** `1.8.7p374`, `1.9.3p545`, and `2.0.0p481` (32 and 64 bit).